# Set a variable into the result from an equation from 2 tables

Tags: sql

Hi everyone I want to create a trigger that will automaticly set the field "Total_Commande" with that equation "contenu_commande.quantite* produit.prix_unitaire". It means (quantity*unit price) But the thing is I am not sure how to do this because I need to take the price from the other table.  So I tried something but I really dont think this the right way. Anyone have a clue ?

Thank you :)

````sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER AjoutTotal
on contenu_commande
after insert
as
begin
update Total_Commande
    set Total_Commande = (SELECT contenu_commande.quantite*produit.prix_unitaire 
                          FROM contenu_commande
                          JOIN produit ON produit.no_produit = contenu_commande.no_produit)
    where no_commande in (SELECT no_commande FROM inserted)
end```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this, didn't test but It should work:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER AjoutTotal
on contenu_commande
after insert
as
begin
update 
    contenu_commande
set 
    Total_Commande =  contenu_commande.quantite*produit.prix_unitaire 
FROM contenu_commande
JOIN produit 
    ON produit.no_produit = contenu_commande.no_produit)
where 
    no_commande in (SELECT no_commande FROM inserted)
end
```